# Change a color of random cell in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to randomly choose a cell and paint it in a color, but I don't know how can I randomly choose a cell, I searched In Google but I didn't find anything useful, I've tried all the examples given by google but nothing works.

I want to save the random generated cell inside a variable and then be able to change its color, value and etc. **How can we do that?**

```vb
Sub RandomCell()
    x = ' Random Cell '
    Range(x).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red '
End Sub
```

**Or maybe even return the cell that was generated**

```vb
Function RandomCell() As Cell 'What is the data type for a cell?`
    x = ' Random Cell '
    Range(x).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red '

    RandomCell = x
End Function
```

Comment: Do you not have any specification on *what* cell? For example, it could just as well be `XFD1048576` the way you have formulated your question currently.

Comment: @JvdV Afaik, a cell is a cell. From `A1` to whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `rnd` function to determine the row and column.

The formula is `Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)`

So assuming you can see roughly 25 rows and 25 columns it would be:

```
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    r = Int((25 * Rnd) + 1)
    c = Int((25 * Rnd) + 1)
    Debug.Print "row: " & r, "column: " & c
    Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = vbRed
```

Returning a cell:

```
Function randomizecell() As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    r = Int((25 * Rnd) + 1)
    c = Int((25 * Rnd) + 1)
    
    Set randomizecell = Cells(r, c)
End Function

Sub colorcell()
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Set cell = randomizecell()
    cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I return the generated cell without painting it? So I can paint it outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Example, you can input your own numbers...

```
Dim ColumnNum As Long
Dim RowNum As Long

ColumnNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 50);
RowNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 5000);

' x = Cells(RowNum, ColumnNum)
' x.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red '

' Or do it immediately:
Cells(Row, Column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red '
```